# How do I create container with checkbox inside for each product

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I'm pretty new to html and I have a question.

[Image how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqhGO.jpg)

So, as you can see in the Image there is individual container with checkbox (checkboxes are for mass deletion) for each product (The products I get from mysql database, the database is working), I was wondering how do I even do something like this ? I've tried searching google for something similar, but nothing comes up :(, could anyone help please ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here You need to add Code so that we can understand where your stuck.. Put little effort add code so that we can help.. No one will give you free code here Please Check [How to ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made something based on your request. the content written inside the box was written inside a 'p' tag(paragraph). just so that you can have an idea.
but you can delete that paragraph and what ever type of content you want.
here is the html and CSS code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="outerbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
        <p class="content">jvc200123 <br>Acme <br>1.00 $<br>size:700 MB</p>
    </div>

</body>

</html>

    
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outerbox {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.checkbox {
  margin: 10px;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.content {
  margin: 10px 25px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: link the CSS file to html page based on your file locations so the code works perfectly.

Comment: This looks actually great, thanks man. The only thing is that I have more questions, if you don't mind. 
First: Is there a way to make html automatically make a box for product when it's added into database ? (I have database and another page where I can add the products to db).

Comment: you can ask me. no problem.

Comment: First: Is there a way to make html automatically make a box for product when it's added into database ? (I have database and another page where I can add the products to db).
Second: Mmm, how can I get those boxes to stack ----> well like in that picture they go 4 columns and then next row, so it looks kinda neat :D

Comment: you can use the html code snippet of that box and paste as many copies as you like and arrange the number of boxes you want in a row and column using CSS grid.

Comment: regarding the automatic addition of the boxes, it takes a lot of java script work and you said you r beginner to the html and css. so its better to use the grid method i told you.